# Is using a third party browser in iOS more secure than Safari?

Tags: ios, safari

I have read that many iOS exploits target the Safari browser. Would using another browser on my iOS device be safer?  Does Safari being a system app give it more access to the OS than a third party browser that I install through the App Store?

Comment: As far as I know, Apple forces all alternative browsers on iOS to use the same engine as Safari anyways. Think of "third-party browsers" as "Safari but with a different UI".

Comment: Per @MechMK1's comment, "Firefox has to use the built-in iOS WebKit-based rendering framework instead of Gecko" --https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_for_iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically not, since all 3rd party browsers on iOS use the **webkit** engine.

A simple way to demonstrate that is with CSS stylesheets, any browser specific attributes such as `-moz` won't be rendered on the Firefox iOs app. Only the non vendor-specific css or webkit attributes.

Therefore all potential vulnerabilities webkit has, apply to **all** browsers inside the iOs ecosystem.